# What's the implication of the word "scene"

Tags: meaning

In a TV documentary we heard the sentence "X announced that, whenever Y happens, they will react by doing Z, as in the *following scene*". After that we saw X doing Z. What is the implication of the word scene?

1. We saw a recording of X actually doing Z
2. We saw a scripted event of X doing Z for the camera
3. We saw some actors disguised as X doing Z
4. No implication at all, "scene" can be used for all of the above

Please note X was a group of anonymous members, so although I skipped the context here, it doesn't give away much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Scene* does carry an implication of something enscenated, so I would not expect to see the real X actually doing something, but rather actors portraying what has been described.

That is not to say that there are no documentaries where X could cooperate and actualy do the acting themselves, so 2 *could* be possible (I recently saw a documentary where a situation was played out by actors, based on teh description of an actual "x", where the actual "X" played a part as well, albeit not themselves...)

When making a documentary, I guess for situation 1 I would not use *scene* but something along the lines of *as can be seen in the following footage*.

Comment: I'd replace it with "section", I think, for a documentary.

Comment: @MaxWilliams it depends on whether ther eis a whole section of the documentary set aside for documenting X doing Z or whether it is indeed just some seconds of footage showing X doing Z. There are plenty of options, but if I have actual footage of X doing Z, the point is that I wouldn't describe it as a _scene_.

Comment: Yes, "section" is quite vague I suppose.  I agree with the main point, that "scene" isn't suitable for things which aren't *staged*, such as real footage.  Some sections of a documentary might be staged though, so could be called scenes perhaps.